# C# code snippets not working after VSIX install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

We've created a number of C# code snippets. If I import them directly using the Code Snippets Manager they work perfectly as intended.

Since we are going to have people rolling into our project at different moments in time we want to ease the on-boarding process so we want to include these snippets into a VSIX project. For that purpose I followed [this process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-distribute-code-snippets) to the letter.

Now there are several issues going on:
1. When I run the VSIX in debug mode I get the experimental instance of visual studio but the scripts' folder is not in the manager and the package does not seem to be installed when I look in the "Extensions and updates".

2. If I close VS and run the VSIX installer, after re-opening VS I can see the package installed in "Extensions and updates", I can see the custom scripts' folder in the scripts manager and all the scripts are there but, when I open a code file and try to use them they are just not available, the short cuts are not recognized and the scripts are not available in the insert script context menu.

We have tried both approaches in three different environments and the behavior is the same.

We are using Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Framework 4.7.1

I have tripled checked all the settings, made sure there aren't any typos, all the files that need to be added are there in the right place so I do not know what else to check or try.

I am sorry that I do not include any code but there are some things that are deemed confidential but I tried doing it with the Hello World example and I got the same result.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turned out, there were multiple causes for this behavior.

**Environment 1**: With the brand new instance of Visual Studio 2017 there was a folder in the Snippets Manager named *%LCID%*. Within this folder there were two snippets specifically for MVC 4 applications. We do not know why but either these snippets or the folder was preventing our custom ones to be detected, once we removed this folder everything started working as expected.

**Environment 2**: This environment did not have the *%LCID%* folder but had ReSharper installed on it and it was configured to use the IntelliJ keyboard schema. As soon as we changed it to use the Visual Studio one then the snippets became available.

**Environment 3**: In this one the *%LCID%* folder was not present and the ReSharper keyboard configuration was set to Visual Studio. We disabled ReSharper and the snippets would still not be available. We basically were never able to figure out why the snippets were not available so we ended up going to the file system, cutting them from the custom folder and pasting them under the "My Snippets" default one and they became available.

Hopefully this information will be useful for someone or, even better, somebody might be able to explain why situations one and three would cause the snippets to not be available.